# GIT: Make a file unique for all branches

Tags: git, file, repository, branch, unique

I need to add some global descriptions ( like howto use the specific repository and other instructions) to a git repository.

Is there a way to assure, that changes can for example only be tracked on master branch and unique for all other branches?

Thank you and best regards,
M.S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.  Within a single repository, you *could* use a pre-commit hook script to reject any commits modifying those files which aren't being made on the master branch.  But, to affect clones of the repository, the hook script would need to be setup in those as well.  And even with that hook in place it's easy to bypass that check.

Comment: ok, bad news, so you prefer an additional place for overall documentation, like for example a forum or wiki?

Comment: I don't see any reason to treat that type of file that much differently than the other files in the repository.

Comment: in this case just because the main folder structure can be modified very often due to the nature of the project.

Comment: But why does that affect those files any more than the other files in the repository?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have solved my problem now using a forum for all users.